# Detect template change in Meteor

Tags: meteor

I'm looking to make an element flash on screen when the underlying collection is updated.

It seems to me that it would make to have an equivalent of Template.my_template.rendered = function(){} which is fired every time the template is updated.

Ideally, this function would not fire the first time the template is rendered.

This is seems like such an obvious use case, am I missing something?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easy to simply include the function in the event that updates the collection.

Comment: Well, I guess that function is in the bowels of meteor somewhere and isn't really the right place to do it.

Answer (score 0):

For Meteor < 0.8

You should use [Template.myTemplate.created](http://docs.meteor.com/#template_created) to do something for the very first time. From the docs [Template.myTemplate.rendered](http://docs.meteor.com/#template_rendered) is fired everytime there is a change *including* the first time. If you want to limit it to only the second time and changes after that (I'm guessing this is what you want), you have to write some custom logic. Currently there is no Meteor api that supports that.

---

For Meteor-0.8

It seems like this API underwent some backwards incompatible [changes](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Blaze#wiki-rendered-callback-only-fires-once) in Meteor-0.8.

There is an elegant way to achieve this as described [Adaptation to the new Meteor rendered callback](https://github.com/avital/meteor-ui-new-rendered-callback/blob/master/new1/client/each.js) here. Bascially you should modify whatever function you are attaching to the variables inside your Template's javascript by calling a helper function once. For example,

```
var renderCount = 1;

var myHelper = function () {
  console.log("rendered #" + renderCount);
  renderCount++;
}; 

Template.myTemplate.myVariable = function () {
  myHelper();
  return this.name;
};
```

Hope this helps. There is also another alternative approach in that same repo. You might like that one.

Comment: The rendered callback used to be called every time a change occurred, but not any more (from version 0.8 and on). Now it's only called when the template been inserted into the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple solution; more discussion here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-talk/iQ37mTP3hLg